# Azure APIM: When developing under self-hosting, can the site be started not under editing mode?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We are developing widgets under the Azure API Management self-hosting model. Currently when we start the site on our local machine with `"npm start"` it will start under admin mode for content editing. Is there a way to start the site locally not in editing mode? The goal is to help speed up our development of UI testing framework.

Comment: Can you try run the command with `npm build`. And run `npm start`  command at `dist` or `build` folder.

Comment: Discovered a new flag for /src/config.design.json file. Add "websitePreviewEnabled": true to the values, and the site will launch locally with a control button in the upper right to toggle between edit and preview mode.